# Using PHP variable inside HTML, in a PHP file

Tags: php, html

I've been trying to get this to work for a while now, and have yet to find a solution online that works. I'm still fairly new to PHP so forgive me if the question is dumb.

I'm using a PHP document to read data from a text file. That PHP document is called as a script to the HTML document which actually displays all the information on the webpage.

So to my understanding, I have to use echo "document.write("")"; to output stuff, which works fine.

However, when I try using variables, it doesn't seem to work. For example I'm trying to do:

```
<?php 
$test = "Hello";
echo "document.write("$test")" ?>
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: you are mixing javascript and PHP

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The specific reason your code is not working is your use of quotes. You can't enclose double-quotes within double quotes unless you escape them first - like this:

```
echo "document.write(\"$test\")" ?>
```

However, there is a deeper problem here. You don't need the Javascript at all. You could just do:

```
echo $test;
```

Lastly, `document.write()` has all sorts of unwanted side effects. If really do need that then you probably want to manipulate the DOM in Javascript directly, but that's a different question.

Comment: I tried using echo $test; in the first place. However, for some reason it showed up blank on the html page. Does anyone have any idea why?

Comment: PHP doesn't get any simpler than `echo $test;`. If that didn't work for you then there's some other problem but there's not enough here to debug it.

Comment: echo is working fine when I use it on the php page itself. But when I try calling it through a script like

    <script src="testingphpscripts.php"></script>

echo seems to not work at all. If  you have any ideas on what's wrong, it would probably help a lot.

Comment: `<script>` is used for loading Javascript into a document. You can't load a PHP script that way. If you're expecting to run a PHP script to generate a Javascript file (which is technically possible) then you really are off at a tangent. If you just want to read a file and send it to the browser all you need is `readfile($filename);` at the right place in your PHP script. No Javascript at all.

Comment: The problem was that I wasn't using include, I was calling the php file as a script. And yeah, I figured out that document.write() was the problem, as it was not printing certain elements of my array, while they definitely existed.

Although your response didn't directly answer my question, it made me realize I was probably going about it the wrong way. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just use `echo` to do what you want:

```
<?php 
$test = "Hello";
echo $test; 
?>
```

Value of $test will be outputted to the html.

Answer (score 0):

`document.write` only works in JavaScript, try just use `echo`

Answer (score 0):

If you want `document.write` to add the value of the `$test` variable in JavaScript, you are almost on the right track, but need to escape your quotation marks:

```
echo "document.write(\"$test\")";
```

Answer (score 0):

because document.write(); is for javascript,to use variable just use variable name only in echo

Answer (score 0):

I don't what you are trying to do, if you want to just output a text into a php usse echo

**Your wrote** it's incorrect

```
<?php 
    $test = "Hello";
    echo "document.write("$test")";
?>
```

**Correct way**

```
<?php 
    $test = "Hello";
    echo $test;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need quotes around the string in the `document.write` :

```
<script>
<?php
    $test = "Hello";
    echo "document.write('" .$test ."');";
?>
</script>
```

Which becomes :

```
<script>
document.write('Hello');
</script>
```

Which in turn displays this on the page :

```
Hello
```

Answer (score 0):

If you  want  output into HTML then you can simply use echo function of PHP.

```
<?php 
$test = "Hello";
echo "<script>document.write('" .$test ."')</script>";
?>
```